# Is it possible to change some product's IP address using python scripts? If possible then how ? Includes Printer and other devices

Tags: python, automation

i am currently on some project. I just want to know if we have more than one products  and need to assign IP address to them **automatically** using python , is this possible.

Comment: This question is so broad that's it's practically unanswerable.  I suppose the answer is yes, __if__ the device provides an interface for doing so.  But some devices may not have such an interface, and among those that do, the details of the interface may differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally: no.

But many devices will use DHCP to configure the network.

So you'd need to configure your DHCP server.